# How to combine the advantages of pagination with authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, pagination, cancan, will-paginate

I have a groups page, where a list of all of its members is displayed.
The Code of the **GroupsController#show** looks something like this

```
  def show
    if @group
      @members = @group.members.order(:last_name, :first_name)
      @members = @members.page(params[:page]).per_page(25) # pagination
    end
    respond_with @group
  end
```

We use authorization with CanCan in our application, and I would like to restrict the displayed members to those, that the user can actually `:read`

Something like this works:

```
      @members = @group.members.order(:last_name, :first_name).select{|member| can? :read, member}
      @members = @members.paginate(params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

But as I understand it would destroy the performance advantages of pagination, that is it would first load all the members from the database and then select the visible ones.
Swapping it around like

```
      @members = @group.members.order(:last_name, :first_name)
      @members = @members.page(params[:page]).per_page(25).select{|member| can? :read, member}
```

won't do either, since the view needs a specific WillPaginate::Collection with meta information like the number of pages, current page etc. - and not a simple Array.

Is there a correct way of doing this like chaining a Proc between the Relation and the Pagination?
My google fu is failing me.

The full code can be seen on [github](https://github.com/fiedl/wingolfsplattform/blob/master/vendor/engines/your_platform/app/controllers/groups_controller.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accessible_by` first to limit your results to those the current user can view:

```
@members = @group.members.accessible_by(current_ability).order(:last_name, :first_name
@members = @members.page(params[:page]).per_page(25) # pagination
```

See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records for more details.